# What does it mean to say "a transformation matrix squish down space to a lower dimension"?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, terminology

If I apply the transformation matrix, A = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 2\\1 & 2 & 5\\2 & 4 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$ to any vector in $R^3$, the vector would be in the plane defined by the two linearly independent vectors in $A$. So, in what dimension does the transformed vector exists?

Since the dimension of the vector space is the cardinality of its basis, is it correct to say that the transformed vector is in 2-dimensional space i.e. $R^2$? I cannot fathom the fact that a vector with $3$ components can exist in the space $R^2$ which has all vectors with $2$ components.squi

On the other hand, since the transformed vector has $3$ components, so it is in the 3-dimensional space i.e. that transformed vector is in $R^3$ too. So, which one is correct?

Comment: It only means the image of any vector lives in a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbf R^3$.

Comment: For example, you can think of the $xy$-plane in 3D space. It is the set of all vectors of the form $(x,y,0)$. You can think of this as a 2D space inside a 3D one.

Comment: @Bernard, But then, what is the co-domain of the transformation function? Is it $R^2$ or $R^3$? If we look at the transformation matrix as a change of basis matrix isn't it fair to say that the new vector lives in $R^2$, since the cardinality of basis is $2$? But then $R^2$ has vectors with 2 components. Perhaps the term "dimension" is being used in different context.

Comment: A $3{\times}3$ real matrix maps $\mathbf R^3$ to itself. $\mathbf R^3$ has subspaces of dimension $2$ and $1$ (these are called, respectively, planes and lines (through the origin)). Also, do you know the *rank-nullity formula*?

Comment: @Bernard, I think I get it now. The transformation matrix $A$ cannot exist in $\mathbf  R^2$ because those $2$ linearly independent column vectors cannot exist in $\mathbf R^2$. So, $A$ exists in the $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbf R^3$ which is quite different from $\mathbf R^2$. Is this correct?  Also, I did a lookup for the _rank-nullity theorem_, however, I fail to see the connection here.

Comment: This theorem, in the present case says that the image of $A$ has dimension $2$ exactly when $\ker A$ has dimension $1$. It was to answer to you objection about the dimensions. To sum up: the image of $A$ has dimension $2$, but is a subspace of a $3$-dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 1):

If the matrix is being applied to a column vector, the new vector lies in the plane
$$ 2x+4y-3z = 0 $$

Try some points as columns $(u,v,w)^T$, see where they go.